# How to filter string before tokenizing in solr

Tags: solr, solr4, solrcloud

We have a requirement to add space to each character before tokenizing it. For example if we have a string "ABCD". I want to send this string to white space tokenizer as "A B C D".

How we can achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Well you are adding space and then sending it to whitespace tokenizer. Can you explain the usecase for doing it so. I assume you want each character to be tokenized and then searched based on that

Comment: Yes you are write. What we are trying to do is wildcard search without using ngrms because it is using too much index size. eg: index data "A B C D E F G" and do a phrase search \*CDE\*

Answer (score 0):

Tokenizers work on input stream and send out tokens. Filters work on each token and send out modified token. Well filter and tokenizers are part of Analyzer. So you can write your own Analyzer. From the source field, you can define a new field with your custom analyzer field type and then index it. You can look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#Specifying_an_Analyzer_in_the_schema). Idea is you write your own analyzer. Once done, you can copy that to your reglar field and use whitespace tokenizer

```
<fieldtype name="nametext" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.YourAnalyzer"/>
</fieldtype>
```

In the given method, you might not be able to use custo filter because that works on token strem, and yours will be before that

Comment: Ramcy, how about using ngrams with min and max values 1? does this does my job?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding what you are looking for is solr.NGramTokenizerFactory with below setup.

Before that, let me present my understanding.

1. You have to index a text (say a name)
2. You have to search the name based on any number of characters (Say min 3 characters are required to search)

Solution: While indexing we will have to split the name into pair of 3 and store so that we can retrieve the same with any combination of pair of 3 characters.

Say input is "aneesh", we have to store as below
ane nee ees esh

This can be achived using below setup.

Here I used minGramSize="3" as this will avoid noise such as a, an, ne etc(provided you are expecting min 3 characters to search)

You can increase maxGramSize to any big number(say 4), so that SOLR will generate that sequences of 4 characters too like anee, nees, eesh

But this is irrelevant, as this tokenizer splits the query string(in query time also to a pair of 3 characters) too as we do for indexing.

```
<fieldType name="text_split" class="solr.TextField" >
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="3"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="3" maxGramSize="3"/>
    </analyzer>         
</fieldType>
```

Out put from Analysis as below
[image]